# How to remove auto generated comments with Microsofts VScode C++ extension?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense, vscode-extensions

When I create an if statement for example, I get this:

```
if (/* condition */)
   {
    /* code */
   }
```

Can I edit the C++ extension settings to remove the auto generated /* condition */ and /* code */ comments?

So it would instead auto format to:

```
if ()
{

}
```

Thanks